# Pandas Python: sort dataframe but don't include given row

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have df which looks like this:

```
Label                      Base
Label                          
Très à gauche              4.51
Très à droite             10.49
Ni à gauche, ni à droite  24.21
Je ne sais pas             5.60
Au centre                  8.69
A gauche                  23.74
A droite                  22.75
```

I would like to sort this in acsending order but I dont want "A gauche" and "A droite" included in the sorting.

The code below does what I want but I'm not sure how to exclude "A gauche" and "A droite" from the sorting.

```
 df_table = df_table.sort(columns="Base",ascending=True)
```

expected output

```
Label                      Base
Label                          
Très à gauche              4.51
Je ne sais pas             5.60
Au centre                  8.69
Très à droite             10.49
Ni à gauche, ni à droite  24.21
A gauche                  23.74
A droite                  22.75
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to filter out the rows you don't want included in your sort operation:

```
d = df_table
condition = (d.Label=='A gauche') | (d.Label=='A droite')
excluded = d[condition]
included = d[~condition]
```

Which can then be sorted

```
sorted = included.sort(columns="Base",ascending=True)
```

And if you want the excluded rows appended to the end of your data frame, you could do this:

```
pandas.concat([sorted,excluded])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Q - What would I do if the rows I didn't want sorted were in the middle, say row 3 and 5?

Comment: You'd either have to do more splitting and concatenation, or maybe you could introduce some kind of weighting function.  It would probably depend on whether you mean 'put this row at position 3 when I'm done sorting' or 'put this row after this other row when I'm done sorting'