# How to split sort a column using the first row's value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, dataframe

My dataset `df` looks like this:

```
time            Open
2017-01-01      2.2475
2017-01-02      3.2180
2017-01-03      5.2128
2017-01-04      1.2128
2017-01-05      2.2128
...., ....
2017-12-31      6.7388
```

I want to sort the `Open` column but by comparing the first `ROW` value in increasing order.

We will have `1st` row value always on the top(`1st row`) and then sort starting the second row by comparing to `1st` row to the closest value in increasing order. All the `low` value is kept on the bottom. Eg: `1.2128`

*[OP seeks a method where values greater than the first row in a select column should appear sequentially and ascending from row 2 to row n, and values less than the first row should then come after n (all of the preceding values).]*

For example, the new `df` would be:

```
time            Open
2017-01-01      2.2475
2017-01-05      2.2128
2017-01-02      3.2180
2017-01-03      5.2128
...., ....
2017-12-31      6.7388
2017-01-04      1.2128
```

**What did I do?**

I can sort by column doing this:

```
df.sort_values(by='Open', ascending=False)
```

but that is by `column`. Now how do I sort by first `ROW` value, which is `2.2475`

Comment: Do you mean sort the `Open` except for the first row? Something like `df.iloc[1:] = df.iloc[1:].sort_values('Open').values`?

Comment: @CodeIt Please kindly review my question completely before marking `Duplicate`. I want to sort by the first value of `ROW`, not the entire column and I need to `include` everything.

Comment: @floss Did you check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26221859/3091398) ?

Comment: @Chris I need to include everything. We will have `1st` row value as it is and then sort starting the second row.

Comment: @floss which is precisely what the code i commented will do :). Please give it a try

Comment: @CodeIt I checked the answer and that is why I put the comment :)

Comment: @floss You can take out the rest of the rows and sort separately and `concat` with the first row.

Comment: @Chris the code removes the `first value`. We will use the `Open` column. From the `first value` of the `first row`, we will sort the remaining preserving the `first row`

Comment: @floss it removes the first line, but the assigned dataframe still has the first row, thereby doing exactly you want. I'll post it as an answer to demonstrate

Comment: @CodeIt as the question states, we are sorting the rest of the `row` by comparing the `first value` of the `Open` column.

Comment: @floss It works in that case too.

Comment: @floss - after running Chris's code, simply calling `print(df)` will return the original frame with all rows sorted just as you like.

Comment: @Chris I have updated the question with more clarity, please help solve it.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, given a `df`:

```
         time    Open
0  2017-01-01  2.2475
1  2017-01-02  3.2180
2  2017-01-03  5.2128
3  2017-01-04  1.2128
4  2017-01-05  2.2128
5  2017-12-31  6.7388
```

OP wants to sort as `row_0`, `(rows greater than row_0)`, (`rows smaller than row_0)`:
This can be achieved using difference between each row and row_0:

```
s = df['Open'].sub(df['Open'][0]).to_dict()
df.iloc[sorted(s, key = lambda x: s.get(x) < 0)]
```

Output:

```
         time    Open
0  2017-01-01  2.2475
1  2017-01-02  3.2180
2  2017-01-03  5.2128
5  2017-12-31  6.7388
3  2017-01-04  1.2128
4  2017-01-05  2.2128
```

Comment: Are we sorting comparing the value of the first row? I just don't want to sort starting the second row... I want to sort by comparing the first value of `Open` row. Can you confirm your code is doing that?

Comment: So you want to use difference? What is your exact definition of _comparing the first value_?

Comment: Not the difference. Let's say `Open` first column value is `4.321`. Now, `sort` the rest of the rows, `2nd`, `3rd`, `4th`, .., `Nth` value by comparing the `1st` value which is `4` in increasing order from the closest match. 4 -> 5 -> 6 and so on.

Comment: @PeptideWitch as I have mentioned, we are not sorting starting `2nd` row. We are sorting from the `2nd` row by comparing it with `1st` row.

Comment: So how does the _comparison_ works? One can compare two numbers by many ways, and _closest_ seems like an absolute difference between two number. If you need to provide another example, please edit the questions to demonstrate your logic :)

Comment: So that'd be something like abs(row(n) - first row).

Comment: @PeptideWitch Precisely. Let's wait for OP to clarify the logic.

Comment: @ post-owner @PeptideWitch I have updated the question with more clarity, please help solve it.

Answer (score 0):

OP is after a method where the first row of a DataFrame column is used as a baseline for a split method of column sorting: values greater than this first row should appear sequentially and ascending from row 2 to row n, and values less than the first row should then come after n (all of the preceding values).

This can be achieved by the following function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-05', '2017-01-06'], 
              'Open': [2.24, 1.21, 1.51, 3.21, 5.21, 6.21]})

def pin_row_and_sort(f):
    values_above = f.loc[f['Open'] >= f['Open'].iloc[0]].sort_values(by='Open')
    values_below = f.loc[f['Open'] < f['Open'].iloc[0]].sort_values(by='Open')
    return pd.concat([values_above, values_below])
                                                   
new_frame = pin_row_and_sort(df)
```

I'd be keen to see any improvements/suggestions on this method.

Comment: Maybe @Chris has a suggestion